# Making an Elastic Object Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two balls (A and B) in my scene, they have some movements when playing. I want to link them by a cylinder, so the top of the cylinder should stick to ball A and the bottom should stick to ball B. And when the balls move the cylinder should move and scale up and down depending on the distance between the balls, so it give an elastic effect.

I made the script bellow and it's working, but the only issue I have is that when a ball move faster, the cylinder didn't follow it at the same speed, so the ball reach the destination then the cylinder after few frames.

**Cylinder Script:**

```
public Transform ball1;
public Transform ball2;
Vector3 scale0;
Vector3 scale;


 void Start()
    {
        scale0 = transform.localScale;
    }

 void Update()
    {
        var pA = ball1.position;
        var pB = ball2.position;

        transform.position = (pA + pB) / 2;
        transform.LookAt(pB); 

        scale = scale0;
        scale.z = scale0.z * Vector3.Distance(pA, pB) * 2;
        transform.localScale = scale;
    }
```

**Ball A Script:**

```
GameObject ActualBase;
GameObject NextBase;
float Speed = 20;

void Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StopAllCoroutines();
            StartCoroutine(Move());
        }
    }

public IEnumerator MoveCylinder()
    {
        Vector3 Ball1Destination = new Vector3(NextBase.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, NextBase.transform.position.z);
        while (Vector3.Distance(transform.localPosition, Ball1Destination) > 0)
        {
            float currentMovementTime = Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Ball1Destination, currentMovementTime * Speed);
            yield return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Tested your script how I guess it is used (more or less - I don't know how your objects look like exactly) but I can't reproduce the bahviour you described ... cylinder follows instantly (see [here](https://imgur.com/Qy20PxB))

Comment: @derHugo Yeah it's working when testing in scene view area, but in my case the ball A move fast with a coroutine method, check my post I've added the Ball A script.

Comment: @derHugo Is it because of coroutine?

Comment: Have you thought of hinge joints?

Comment: @Everts How can I do that?

Comment: It is a component from Unity engine, you can find plenty of video and tutorials about it. It is meant to reproduce chain physics but you can use it for an elastic.

Comment: @Everts I tried it, but there's still a time lag between the ball and the cylinder

Comment: @derHugo Any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to script execution order. If you change anything with Update(), an Update() on another script might, or might not 'see' the change for the current frame. One way to manage this is to manually change ScriptExectutionOrder in the player settings, but its very messy.

A slightly less messy way is to use a lesser known callback called LateUpdate (which is guaranteed to run later than other updates, essentially).

Easy to overuse but useful